# While running google app engine application I encountered Bind error?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py",
>   line 315, in start
>       self._start_all_fixed_port(host_ports)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py",
>   line 352, in _start_all_fixed_port
>       raise BindError('Unable to bind %s:%s' % self.bind_addr) google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to
>   bind localhost:8000

Comment: Do you have anything else running on port 8000, or have you recently stopped something that used port 8000?

Comment: @WanderNauta How do I check if there's anything running on port 8000?

Comment: You'd open, say, a browser and go to `http://localhost:8000`.

Comment: It says HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Comment: I tried changing admin port using command line but that didn't work so I created a new application with different admin port and now it's working.